# Maintain old filename while updating with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

With carrierwave, I'd like to change the image without changing the location(filename). This way, all links to the old image will still work, but point to the new picture.

For example, I upload an image 'promotion1.png'. I link to this image in an editor. Afterwards, I have a new promotion (promotion2.png), and want to update the image without having to go to the editor again. So old filename points to the new file.

How can this be done? I don't want to be forced to use the same filename. I = an unwitting client :)

Comment: You could create a before upload method that will move the old file to a temp name and then back to the original name after upload is complete.